# Load without casting

Tags: java

I have a parent clas that all children classes extends. In the parent I have a method, "Load", to load data from the database. My problem is if I have a static method that receives the class name and id, I must cast the object when I get it from the method.

Method example:

```
public static <className> Load(Class<?> className, int id) {

    // Create instance form class name
    Parent object = createInstanceFromClass(className);

    // Populate object

    retrun object;
}
```

//Method call

```
Child object = (Child) Child.Load(Child.this,1);
```

So I want to remove tihs extra cast when loading children object.

Am I even using the right way to do it?

Comment: A `Class` object isn't the name of a class. It's much, much more than that. Why would you call it `className`?

Comment: You can't use generics is a static context. If you can have that method non static, it can be done be using generics.

Comment: @rekaszeru: You can, though you can't use the class's type parameters. Generic methods still work fine.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right, I was thinking forward on a <T extends YourAbstractClass> way. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @rekaszeru you **can** use generic in `static` context.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: No, I mean if you have a class `Foo<T>` with a static `bar` method, `Foo.bar` doesn't have access to `T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're creating the object through reflection, this may work:

```
public static <T extends Parent> T load(Class<T> clazz, int id)
    throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    T object = clazz.newInstance(); //createInstanceFromClass(className);
    //populate object...
    return object;
}
```

If you don't want to throw any checked exception:

```
public static <T extends Parent> T load(Class<T> clazz, int id) {
    try {
        T object = clazz.newInstance(); //createInstanceFromClass(className);
        //populate object...
        return object;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
        //handle the exception here...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public static <T extends Parent> T Load(Class<T> className, int id){
    // create instance form class name
    Parent object= createInstanceFromClass(className);

    // populate object

    return (T) object;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the return type and the `Class` on the `className` parameter. The type of `object` may also need changing.

Comment: This code would generate a warning about casting to a generic class not being typesafe.  Better would be `className.cast(object)` rather than `(T) object`.

Comment: Lol .. Sorry guys .. I'll fix .. is fixed `retrun` , ps Luiggi's is Completely correct accept that answer